# Solr omitNorms=false doesn't work

Tags: xml, solr

As I know by default **omitNorms** is set to false, but somehow scores don't affect at all.
It always shows same scores for all fields.

```
{
        "MediaOutletName":"Guardian Money",
        "score":6.101774},
      {
        "MediaOutletName":"The Guardian",
        "score":6.101774},
      {
        "MediaOutletName":"Farmers Guardian",
        "score":6.101774},
      {
        "MediaOutletName":"Guardian Online",
        "score":6.101774},
      {
        "MediaOutletName":"Thames Guardian",
        "score":6.101774},
      {
```

In this example **The Guardian** should be on the top and gets more scores than others.

Filter:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" types="wdfftypes.txt" generateNumberParts="0" stemEnglishPossessive="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" generateWordParts="1" splitOnNumerics="1"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt" tokenizerFactory="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" types="wdfftypes.txt" generateNumberParts="1" stemEnglishPossessive="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" generateWordParts="1" splitOnNumerics="1"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Field definition

```
 <field name="MediaOutletName" omitNorms="false"  type="text_general" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

**Debug query**

```html
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"MediaOutletName:Guardian",
      "indent":"on",
      "fl":"MediaOutletName_s,score",
      "omit":"undefined",
      "wt":"json",
      "debugQuery":"on",
      "_":"1471275424357"}},
  "response":{"numFound":55,"start":0,"maxScore":6.101774,"docs":[
      {
        "MediaOutletName_s":"Guardian Money",
        "score":6.101774},
      {
        "MediaOutletName_s":"The Guardian",
        "score":6.101774},
      {
        "MediaOutletName_s":"Farmers Guardian",
        "score":6.101774},
      {
        "MediaOutletName_s":"Guardian Online",
        "score":6.101774},
      {
        "MediaOutletName_s":"Thames Guardian",
        "score":6.101774},
      {
        "MediaOutletName_s":"Nenagh Guardian",
        "score":6.101774},
      {
        "MediaOutletName_s":"News Guardian",
        "score":6.101774},
      {
        "MediaOutletName_s":"Gorey Guardian",
        "score":6.101774},
      {
        "MediaOutletName_s":"Cornish Guardian",
        "score":6.101774},
      {
        "MediaOutletName_s":"Somerset Guardian",
        "score":6.101774}]
  },
  "debug":{
    "rawquerystring":"MediaOutletName:Guardian",
    "querystring":"MediaOutletName:Guardian",
    "parsedquery":"MediaOutletName:guardian",
    "parsedquery_toString":"MediaOutletName:guardian",
    "explain":{
      "301":"\n6.101774 = weight(MediaOutletName:guardian in 110) [], result of:\n  6.101774 = score(doc=110,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:\n    5.4649 = idf(docFreq=55, docCount=13111)\n    1.116539 = tfNorm, computed from:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      3.436885 = avgFieldLength\n      2.56 = fieldLength\n",
      "332":"\n6.101774 = weight(MediaOutletName:guardian in 125) [], result of:\n  6.101774 = score(doc=125,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:\n    5.4649 = idf(docFreq=55, docCount=13111)\n    1.116539 = tfNorm, computed from:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      3.436885 = avgFieldLength\n      2.56 = fieldLength\n",
      "4897":"\n6.101774 = weight(MediaOutletName:guardian in 1016) [], result of:\n  6.101774 = score(doc=1016,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:\n    5.4649 = idf(docFreq=55, docCount=13111)\n    1.116539 = tfNorm, computed from:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      3.436885 = avgFieldLength\n      2.56 = fieldLength\n",
      "6923":"\n6.101774 = weight(MediaOutletName:guardian in 2270) [], result of:\n  6.101774 = score(doc=2270,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:\n    5.4649 = idf(docFreq=55, docCount=13111)\n    1.116539 = tfNorm, computed from:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      3.436885 = avgFieldLength\n      2.56 = fieldLength\n",
      "8553":"\n6.101774 = weight(MediaOutletName:guardian in 2970) [], result of:\n  6.101774 = score(doc=2970,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:\n    5.4649 = idf(docFreq=55, docCount=13111)\n    1.116539 = tfNorm, computed from:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      3.436885 = avgFieldLength\n      2.56 = fieldLength\n",
      "8680":"\n6.101774 = weight(MediaOutletName:guardian in 3045) [], result of:\n  6.101774 = score(doc=3045,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:\n    5.4649 = idf(docFreq=55, docCount=13111)\n    1.116539 = tfNorm, computed from:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      3.436885 = avgFieldLength\n      2.56 = fieldLength\n",
      "8686":"\n6.101774 = weight(MediaOutletName:guardian in 3049) [], result of:\n  6.101774 = score(doc=3049,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:\n    5.4649 = idf(docFreq=55, docCount=13111)\n    1.116539 = tfNorm, computed from:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      3.436885 = avgFieldLength\n      2.56 = fieldLength\n",
      "8961":"\n6.101774 = weight(MediaOutletName:guardian in 3203) [], result of:\n  6.101774 = score(doc=3203,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:\n    5.4649 = idf(docFreq=55, docCount=13111)\n    1.116539 = tfNorm, computed from:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      3.436885 = avgFieldLength\n      2.56 = fieldLength\n",
      "9253":"\n6.101774 = weight(MediaOutletName:guardian in 3396) [], result of:\n  6.101774 = score(doc=3396,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:\n    5.4649 = idf(docFreq=55, docCount=13111)\n    1.116539 = tfNorm, computed from:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      3.436885 = avgFieldLength\n      2.56 = fieldLength\n",
      "9344":"\n6.101774 = weight(MediaOutletName:guardian in 3448) [], result of:\n  6.101774 = score(doc=3448,freq=1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n), product of:\n    5.4649 = idf(docFreq=55, docCount=13111)\n    1.116539 = tfNorm, computed from:\n      1.0 = termFreq=1.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      3.436885 = avgFieldLength\n      2.56 = fieldLength\n"},
    "QParser":"LuceneQParser",
    "timing":{
      "time":0.0,
      "prepare":{
        "time":0.0,
        "query":{
          "time":0.0},
        "facet":{
          "time":0.0},
        "facet_module":{
          "time":0.0},
        "mlt":{
          "time":0.0},
        "highlight":{
          "time":0.0},
        "stats":{
          "time":0.0},
        "expand":{
          "time":0.0},
        "debug":{
          "time":0.0}},
      "process":{
        "time":0.0,
        "query":{
          "time":0.0},
        "facet":{
          "time":0.0},
        "facet_module":{
          "time":0.0},
        "mlt":{
          "time":0.0},
        "highlight":{
          "time":0.0},
        "stats":{
          "time":0.0},
        "expand":{
          "time":0.0},
        "debug":{
          "time":0.0}}}}}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Was omitNorms set to false when you indexed? What does `debugQuery` show?

Comment: @MatsLindh please have a look I have updated my code.I have re-imported data with omitNorms "true" and "false" a lot of times, no reaction at all.As you can see 2.56 = fieldLength shows for every field same length;

Answer (score 1):

When talking about field length in Lucene / Solr / Elastic, you're talking about [the number of *tokens*](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html#formula_norm), not the number of bytes in the field. All your examples have two tokens, and therefore get the same score from length normalization applied.

If the field is single valued, you could additionally index an integer value as the field length in bytes and use that as a tie breaker when sorting. I don't think there's a function query to get the length of the raw value of a field to do this runtime (at least there wasn't earlier).

Comment: In this case, it will break a sorting logic with multiple sorting fields. For Example: score desc,fieldLength asc,Importance asc,IsParent (4 sorting options)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - if the scores where different because of length norms, the third and fourth sort arguments wouldn't do anything anyway (which is the same as what you'd get by using the fieldLength as an explicit sort)?

Comment: Sorting by length would work only if queries are simple. In mycase case queries are more complicated and I can't use field length as a sorting parameter. (((MediaOutletName:Guardian*^20)) OR ((MediaOutletName:Guardian^20))) OR (((About:Guardian*)) OR ((About:Guardian))) OR (((Contributions:Guardian*)) OR ((Contributions:Guardian))) OR (((PleaseNote:Guardian*)) OR ((PleaseNote:Guardian))) OR (((Readership:Guardian*)) OR ((Readership:Guardian))) OR (((MediaOutletNameAlias:Guardian*^20)) OR ((MediaOutletNameAlias:Guardian^20))) OR (((Content:Guardian*)) OR ((Content:Guardian))) )

Comment: You could also use the value as small boosting factor instead, you can use a `bq` to massage the value of the field into a small-ish factor, nesting the fields as needed (but it'd be hard to decide which field generated the hit (but using query() can help, but you have quite a number of fields - so not sure about the performance)).